# Has -A Relationship in java

Tags: java

```
public class Horse extends Animal {
    private Halter myHalter = new Halter();
    public void tie(LeadRope rope) {
        myHalter.tie(rope); // Delegate tie behavior to the
      // Halter object
    }
}

public class Halter {
    public void tie(LeadRope aRope) {
    // Do the actual tie work here
}
}
```

In this example Horse has-a Halter.Can we call **myHalter.tie(rope);** like this:

```
public class Horse extends Animal {
    private Halter myHalter = new Halter();

        myHalter.tie(rope); // Without using the public void tie method

}
```

It gives an error. My explanation to this is that its not a main() method but could anyone explain it in a better way.

Comment: Is the code `myHalter.tie(rope);` in a method? Or this is the exact code you have? If it is not - this is the issue.

Comment: Think when do you want it to be invoked, and put it the right place. If you want it to be invoked during the initialization of the object, put it in a constructor. If during a method - put it in a method.

Comment: What do you want to do? If you tell us, perhaps we'll be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Statements other than variable/field declarations in a class body must be put into a **method body**, a **constructor** or an **initializer block**. For example, it would be OK if you attempt to compile this code:

```
public class Horse {

    private Halter myHalter = new Halter();

    {
       myHalter.tie(new LeadRope());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant call method in class block , you have to create a method and than you can call a method in the body of a method, or you can call a method in static, instance or constructor block

Answer (score 1):

Ok try this....

**-** `Has-A relationship` is known as `Composition`.

```
public class Bathroom{

 Tub tub;


}


public class Tub{



}
```

**-** We can say that `Bathroom` has a **reference of type** `Tub`, that means `Bathroom` has an **instance variable** of type `tub`.